# I get different instances of the same singleton object when imported through different modules in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, singleton, node-modules, async-hooks

I have module A that uses a singleton pattern to create an object which needs to be shared.

```
A.js:
...
let instance = undefined;

module.exports {
 init: function () {
  if(!instance)
     instance = new Instance();
 },
 getSomeValue: function () {
   return instance.get();
 },
};
```

I've got two different modules B and C, where each depends on the same module A,

```
B.js

const { init, getSomeValue } = require('A');

function middleware1(req, res, next) {
  init();
  next();
}

module.export = middleware1;
```

```
C.js

const { getSomeValue } = require('A');

function middleware2(req, res, next) {
  console.log(getSomeValue()); // throws undefined, can not recognise initialisation by B module
  next();
}

module.export = middleware2;
```

```
main application:

...

app.use(middleware1());
app.use(middleware2());
...
```

but there are separate copies of that dependent module under the node_modules subdirectory of each of the two different modules.
I want to initialize `instance` once no matter from which library/module it is instantiated and want to share the object across all the libraries/modules using it under the same project.

How can I access the `instance` state that I want to share across the complete node project?

Comment: Isn't the `get` export supposed to be returning `instance` itself? Like: `get: () => return instance`

Comment: @ionizer `get` is supposed to return some value inside the `instance` object. I do not want to return the `instance` object to the outer world. but to avoid confusion, editing the question from `get` to `getSomeValue`

Comment: Ok but you are still not `return`ing the value from the exported function, like `getSomeValue: function() { return instance.get() }` which is probably you're getting `undefined`

Comment: You also have a syntax issue : ``app.use(middleware2();``